# Django - Redirecting to a view with <select> <option>

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm taking my first steps on django, and i'm stuck with this problem:

I'm planning to use a **selection box** to **choose a chapter** of the book/novel and **be redirected to it**. Either using a "go" button or just redirecting instantly. Preferably the latter. But i don't really know how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/<int:pk>', views.ChapterView.as_view(), name='chapter_view'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Numero')
    chapter_novel = models.ForeignKey(Novel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Novel')
    chapter_title = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Titulo')
    chapter_content = models.TextField()
    chapter_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    chapter_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Chapter {self.chapter_number}'


    def similar_chapter(self):
        return Chapter.objects.filter(chapter_novel=self.chapter_novel)
```

views.py

```
class ChapterView(DetailView):
    model = Chapter
    context_object_name = 'chapter'
    template_name = 'chapter.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['chapter_group'] = Chapter.similar_chapter(self.get_object())
        context['novel'] = Novel.objects.get(novel_title=self.get_object().chapter_novel)
        return context
```

HTML

```
<form>
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>{{ chapter.chapter_number }} - {{ chapter.chapter_title }}</option>
    {% for capitulos in chapter_group %}
    <option value="{% url 'chapter_view' novel.id capitulos.pk %}">
        {{ capitulos.chapter_number }} - {{ capitulos.chapter_title }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
```

I tried using an <a href={% url 'chapter_view' novel.id capitulos.pk %}> inside the option, to no avail. Now i'm searching ways to do it, but haven't found nothing using .as_view() like i'm using.

Comment: Can you share the `Chapter` model as well as entire html form?

Comment: It's currently without a form tag, since i wasn't sure how to handle it

Comment: So, how you are handling it without a form tag?

Comment: I'm not really understanding how can i make it do something like "when clicked,, send me to the chapter_view using the parameters novel.id and  capitulos.pk"